# How do I get the count of records where value in my column is <java> (String) in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

In my table BookDetails, I have a column Language wherein there are different languages such as php, java, sql etc.
    Now I want to know the number of records where language is "java"

```
HELP ME COMPLETE THE CODE

public Long getBookCount(){
        Session session ;
        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().   
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Criteria too:

```
return (Number) 
session.createCriteria(Book.class)add(Restrictions.eq("language", "Java))
              .setProjection(Projections.rowCount())
              .uniqueResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code .

```
Query query = session.createQuery(
        "select count(*) from BookDetails b where b.language=:language ");
query.setString("language", "java");
Long count = (Long)query.uniqueResult();
```